# Open WebView in an AlertDialog iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to open up a `WebView` inside of an `AlertDialog` on iPhone? If you wouldn't mind providing an example I would be very appreciative.

Comment: You want to add a web view to a UIAlertView?  Don't do that! UIAlert view is not meant to be extensively modified (look at [UIAlertView documentation's "Subclassing Notes" section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)).  My suggestion would be to create your own UIView with a WebView inside it and then present it modally

Comment: @Michael Dautermann It was my only idea for placing these ads so they are easy to get rid of. I'm using Leadbolt and using an App Wall. The problem with it is if it is just a webview it takes over the screen and they can't get to a section in my app without it being in the way. On Android I added an alert box and placed the webview in so they could just dismiss the ad with a simple button click. Any alt ideas to accomplish that? A button on the webview to exit the webview

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments, I have to echo the sentiment that you really don't want to do that! Possible, sure, but very much against Apple's guidelines and harder than you need. Just load a `UIWebView` modally, like Words With Friends does, and use either a `UIButton` inserted into the view in the corner or bottom to dismiss it. The view could even be a fullscreen `UIView` with a `UIWebView` and `UIButton` inserted into the view to make the hierarchy make more sense. Any questions about how to accomplish this? Happy to give more information.